# How to pass multiple params to express with the AngularJS service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-http

I have passed two params from client to express endpoint it gives me results on my local machine but when i deploy to linux server its not working no errors and no response ? Do you think it could be params issue ?

client.js

```
getServerSearch:function(str,strEnv){
                    return $http.get("/serverSearch?searchTxt=" + str + '&searchEnv=' + strEnv);
         }
```

server.js

```
app.get('/serverSearch', function (req, res) {
    var searchTxt = req.query.searchTxt;
    var searchEnv = req.query.searchEnv;

            searchFileService.readFile(searchTxt,searchEnv,function(lines,err){
                        console.log('Logs',lines);
                          if (err)
                           return res.send();
                           res.json(lines);
                    });
    console.log('Search text', searchTxt);
})
```

;

Comment: Have you tried putting console.log messages to show what values `searchTxt` and `searchEnv` have before the `...readFile()` ? And if so, what were the results?

Comment: values are not even printing in server.js before we call `searchFileService.readFile` thats why i raised this question

Comment: You can have as many query params as you want (up to some very long string length limit) so it is unlikely that is your issue.  I'd suggest you should just do a console.log on `req.originalUrl` and on `req.query` to see what you are getting that is different.  This seems like basic debugging that would take only a few minutes to discover what is different using the debugger or `console.log()` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain ASCII characters and unicode points larger than 127 need to be properly encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and replaced with [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

The AngularJS $http service has a built-in param serializer to do that.

```
function getServerSearch(str,strEnv){
    //return $http.get("/serverSearch?searchTxt=" + str + '&searchEnv=' + strEnv);

    var params = {};
    params.searchTxt = str;
    params.searchEnv = strEnv;

    return $http.get("/serverSearch", { params: params })
        .catch(function(errorResponse) {
            console.log(errorResponse);
            throw errorResponse;
        });

}
```

Also it is wise to include a rejection handler to see any internal framework errors or errors returned from the server.

Also see [MDN JavaScript reference - encodeURIComponent().](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: i changed code according to your answer but it still did resolve my issue

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. I will leave this **answer for other reader** who are searching for **"How to pass multiple parameters."**